# Symfony2, how to render controller's action in a twig template if controller has a constructor

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, twig

From the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers) I learned how to embed a Controller in a Twig template.

The problem appears when the Controller has injected properties. Is there a way to use Twig's `render(controller())` function with Controllers that have a constructor?

When I try following:

```
{{ render(controller(
  'SomeBundle:Some:renderList',
  { 'request': app.request }
)) }}
```

I get this error:
`Missing argument 1 for SomeBundle\Controller\SomeController::__construct()`

Constructor for this Controller look like that:

```
public function __construct($container, SomeService $someService) {
  parent::__construct($container);
  $this->someService = $someService;
}
```

Injection of the container and someService is configured in service.yml.

So again, my question is: how to embed controller in Twig's template when this controller uses Dependency Injection?

**UPDATE**

I could do like so:
`{{ render(app.request.baseUrl ~ '/some/route') }}`
But I would like to avoid making routes.

**UPDATE 2**

Service definition from service.yml

```
some.controller:
    class: SomeBundle\Controller\SomeController
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@some.service"]
```

Comment: Do you have properly define your controller as a Service ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods

Comment: @Smashou Thank you for your question. Yes, I do defined my controller as a service correctly.

Comment: You can just use the service name like `{{ render(controller('some.controller')) }}` in the same way the Sylius project does (https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig#L140-L145). You might not need to pass the request over too all though I could be wrong with that.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong but I triend with '@' and without it and in both cases got this error: Unable to parse the controller name "some.controller"

Comment: @Qoop it worked. Where were you 2 hours ago?! That is the perfect answer. I will update my question with it as alternative.

Comment: I'll add it as an alternative answer so it's more visible.

Comment: I strongly advise you to **not** use ```render```. It creates a subrequest which will itself load the fullstack framework again, increasing the load on your server and the pageload time. You can create a service (with @templating injected) and add it to twig globals and call that.

Comment: I am experimenting and looking for a good solution to update only a partial/fragment of the page. Something like change filters in the form and update results.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard is right, my solution is the good one or at least should :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have a simple controller defined as a service in which i inject a template engine on its constructor. However i'm getting the same error message as the op when calling it from twig.
I'm trying the following:

`{{ render(controller('mycontroller', {'arg1': val1}) }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For controllers as service you just need to use the service name (`@some.controller`) and action (`yourAction`) rather than the controller shortcut (`SomeBundle:Some:renderList`) as you can see in the [Sylius templates](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig#L140-L145).

So it would be...

```
{{ render(controller('some.controller:yourAction')) }}
```

If you are Symfony 2.4+ you can make use of the `request_stack` to get the request rather than passing it in as an argument like..

```
$request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
```

Comment: For me, it's not working. I've defined a controller as a service but i get the following error: `Unable to parse the controller name "gridview.controller".`, where `gridview.controller` is my service name.
I'm calling this way in the view: `{{ render(controller('gridview.controller')) }}`

Comment: Thanks. But now i'm getting another issue. My controller has a template engine injected on its constructor. When called this way, i get the following message: `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to GridviewBundle\Widget\Grid::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface, none given`. Any clue?

Comment: If it's a different issue you should create a new question. I can only assume you are either not injecting the `@templating` service in your service definition or it has yet to be initialised when your controller is set up.

Answer (score 5):

If you have defined your controller as a service, you need to "inject" it into twig in order to make it available and correctly instantiated.

I suggest to create twig global variable

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        cc: "@comparison.controller"
```

Then you can use one of the methods (actions?)

```
{{ cc.foo(aBarVariable) }}
```

#### Alternative answer

You could create a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) where you could inject your service in order to make it available for views

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does work. One last question though. Render function from controller returns this line too: HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Wed, 25 Feb 2015 09:24:06 GMT. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @greg: I'm a little bit confused, what is a "rid"?

Comment: Nevermind. I will deal with that on my own. Thank you again for your input. You helped.

Comment: I had to use controller's function renderView instead of render to prevent cache headers from being rendered. Just in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: If you had to use renderView then you still have something wrong.